# >&[FILE_DESCRIPTOR] vs >& file bash redirection operators

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I have been reading about bash redirection, and encountered those two articles about it

- first one :

  https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect

  stating that

  > You can use &[FILE_DESCRIPTOR] to reference a file descriptor value;

  however when i was reading it simultaneously with the second article
- second one

  https://catonmat.net/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three

  it stated that

  > Also note that in bash, writing this:
  >
  > ```
  > $ command &>file
  > ```
  >
  > Is exactly the same as:
  >
  > ```
  > $ command >&file
  > ```
  >
  > The first form is preferred however.

how come `>&file` make `file` a file descriptor

Comment: Note that the string `file` is not an integer. So `>&file` would not somehow be interpreted as `>&n` where `n` is some integer value (as in `>&1`).

Answer (score 4):

It's actually two different operators which conflict with each other, one from the Bourne shell, one from the C shell.

```
cmd >&2
```

Short for

```
cmd 1>&2
```

Is the Bourne shell operator that runs `cmd` with its stdout (fd 1) connected to the same resource (same *open file description*) as that on fd 2 (`x>&y` (or `x<&y` which is exactly the same) redirects  fd x to the same resource as on fd y).

```
cmd >& file
```

Is the C shell (`csh`) operator that runs `cmd` with both its fd 1 and 2 connected to a new *open file description* obtained by opening `file` in write-only mode. In Bourne shell syntax, the equivalent would be `cmd > file 2>&1`

They do conflict. Which one is actually used depends on whether the target is numerical or not.

If you have:

```
cmd >&"$file"
```

The Bourne shell operator will be used if `$file` contains a sequence of decimal digits and the C shell operator will be used otherwise!

That's why it's better to avoid that csh operator and use the Bourne shell syntax (`> file 2>&1`) instead.

`bash` (and `zsh`) also has a `&>` operator as an alternative to `>&`, but note that it breaks POSIX compliance as `cmd &> file` is meant to run `cmd &` and then `> file` in POSIX `sh`. It does however not have the conflict problem mentioned above.